# Compiling Nano with UTF-8 support on one computer failed

Tags: compiling, unicode, nano

I want to compile Nano from source for my friend.

I have successfully compiled it on all of my computers and he's having Linux Mint 18.1 too.

I don't know why; or better said I don't know what is missing in his system for UTF-8 support as per this configuration message:

> ```
> *** Insufficient UTF-8 support was detected in your curses and/or C
> *** libraries.  If you want UTF-8 support, please verify that your slang
> *** was built with UTF-8 support or your curses was built with wide
> *** character support, and that your C library was built with wide
> *** character support.
> ```

I tried to install various development packages and it solved several other issues, but this one I am unable to solve since I didn't manage to google much about this issue.

I am quite exhausted, so I temporarily installed the compiled Nano editor with disabled UTF-8 support on his computer.

Any clues appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you need to install `libncursesw5-dev` and/or `libslang2-dev`; that’s what’s missing according to the config log.